# I mistakeanly sent my tokens to the BSC contract address

Tags: evm, bsc, recovery, recover

I mistakeanly sent YOURAI to the BSC contract address 0x27f16d9a5095b763baeadd7dd78e83288af . Can someone please take a look at the contract and see if the tokens can be recovered?** Thank you.

I send the all tokens here : 0x27f16d9a5095b763baeadd7dd78e83288af29cf4

Txid:https://bscscan.com/tx/0x882cf8aff727454e4934c985c9fe8df329f59083eda83eab7fc98f6c48e505a0